# How to create a list from JSON objects using the GSON library?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I have this json :

```
{
  "Pikachu": {
    "id": "266",
    "name": "Pikachu"
  },
  "Pichu": {
    "id": "103",
    "name": "Pichu"
  },
  "Raichu": {
    "id": "84",
    "name": "Raichu"
  }
}
```

and this model :

```
class Pokemon: Serializable {

    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: String = ""

    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String = ""
}
```

How can i get ?

```
//retrofit call
@GET("/pokemon")
fun getPokemon(): Call<List<Pokemon>>
```

if we assume that `/pokemon` is the correct path to display the json above

```
// what i need : [Pokemon@1, Pokemon@2, Pokemon@3]
```

Comment: `<List<Pokemon>` will expect you to deserialize the JSONArray, while you have the JSONObject. In general, your JSON is badly structured. It should be like `[
  {
    "id": "266",
    "name": "Pikachu"
  },
   {
    "id": "103",
    "name": "Pichu"
  }]` instead.

Comment: Hi! I agree with you but unfortunately I can't change the Json :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, below code will convert your **JSON object** to **List** using GSON library

```
String jsonStr = "{\"Pikachu\": {\"id\": \"266\",\"name\": \"Pikachu\"},\"Pichu\": {\"id\": \"103\",\"name\": \"Pichu\"},\"Raichu\": {\"id\": \"84\",\"name\": \"Raichu\"}}";

private List<Pokemon> getPokemonObjects() {
    try {
        List<Pokemon> pokemonList = new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject.keys();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            String key = iterator.next();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Pokemon pokemon = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.get(key).toString(),Pokemon.class);
            pokemonList.add(pokemon);
        }

       return pokemonList;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to those who helped me but I prefer your solution because it answers my question exactly.

Comment: pokemonList.map { it.name } = {ArrayList@8818}  size = 3    
0 = "Pikachu""
1 = "Pichu
2 = "Raichu" //it works

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Map` instead of `List`. List is for json array. You can return `Call<Map<String, Pokemon>>` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ok I don't think I have much choice... I'll only do `map.value`... the keys are useless for me (this json is really bad)